# Connections not working when loading window from nib file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos

I'm launching a new window with a nib file as below:

```
Workbench* workbench = [[Workbench alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WorkbenchView"];
[workbench showWindow:self];
```

However, none of the connections that I've made in Interface Builder seem to work. What do I need to do to have access to these outlets?

Comment: is the Window connected in your nib?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out that I was trying to set delegates, etc too early in the init method. I moved my code to awakeFromNib and am now able to access everything just fine.